# How to scroll with Chromedp Go parser?

Tags: go

I am parsing Google reviews from Google maps. They have an interface where you get eight reviews and then you need to scroll and they lazy-load the rest of them.

I have been stuck for three days with this issue and cannot make things work. I tried to `Scrollintoview` all of the DOM nodes but to no effect.

Here is the page and I need to scroll left panel.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Starbucks/@42.040939,-87.7331847,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x880fcf9be1d47233:0xfe201c7e7e5b1ed5!8m2!3d42.040935!4d-87.730996

Can someone give me a direction to continue my research?

Comment: Google has an API for getting location and review information from maps.

Comment: I may be wrong but you can take only the last 5 reviews. Or maybe you have other info?